# Why this concatenation method is not importing headers?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, header, glob

I was using this piece of code to concatenate several excel spredsheets into one(Using python 3 and Pandas):

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("name*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=False)
    all_data = all_data[df.columns]
```

It worked for several times, but now it is not importing headers. I checked the files they all have same headers in same order. What can be wrong here?

Comment: post full code and short part example (picture) of how the excel looks like. Include os and versions of software as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It aws an error with encoding during exporting the spreadsheet.(propably) When I exported files on my PC i worked flawelessly.
Sorry for your trouble.